# Is it necessary to change to flex sdk 4.5 in order to work with flash player 11

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5, flashplayer-10

I hava a project in flashdevelop 4.0 and I used flex sdk 4.0.

Although I add support for FP 11 in flex config  file and also in project settings and compiler options, I still get my project stated after comiplation in FP 10 not FP 11. (I uninstalled FP 10 with adobe unninstaller).

And also when I embed the swf in html page with swfobject I keep getting that I need to install FP 11 which is already installed.

So I am asking is it neccesary to migrate to flex sdk 4.5 in order to use FP 11?

If this is not a programming question than move it, but I dont know where to place it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Player 11 will be available in Flex 4.6 SDK / Flash Builder 4.6.

You can follow steps to target Flash Player 11 in Flex 4.5, such as:
http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2011/09/20/creating-a-custom-flex-4-5-sdk-to-target-flash-11-and-air-3/
http://www.disturbmedia.com/wiki/How_to_get_started_with_the_Molehill_API_and_Away3D_40.html

Builds of Flex 4.6 SDK should be available soon:
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+4.6

Comment: Do you know if Flash Builder 4.6 is going to cost money to upgrade to from 4.5.

Comment: My understanding is that it will be a free upgrade: http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2011/09/flex-and-flash-builder-4-6-and-pre-release.html